# How to install psycopg2 for python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pip

While isntaling binaryanalysis Iv got an error ImportError: No module named psycopg2 but I have installed it but its only avalible for python 3.5. How I can install it for python2.7 ?

Python 3.5

```
$ python3.5
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
>>> exit
Use exit()
```

Python 2.7

```
$ python2.7
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
>>>
```

Edit:

```
$ pip install psycopg2 
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

Comment: Do you have pip installed for python 2.7?

Comment: Probably not, I dont know, how I can check ?

Comment: What OS or distro do you use? Can you run `pip2 --version` or `pip27 --version`?

Comment: Im on ubuntu 16.04 and no pip2 its not instaled

Comment: Oh yes `$ pip2 install psycopg2` it took me some time, can you post your anwer I will accept it, tnx

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

I did this for Python 2.7, not sure if it works for Python 3.6